# How to show splash screen in React native expo app

Tags: react-native, expo, splash-screen, react-native-splash-screen

I have tried to display splash screen for my app it's working well and splash screen is shown in localhost for both android and ios. but after made a build, my Testflight version of the app did not show the splash screen it only shows white screen. I faced a issue on ios only. For android apk file shows splashscreen. how do display the splash screen in .ipa files for react native expo app.

this is my app.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "ShoppingStore",
    "slug": "ShoppingStore",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-image-picker",
        {
          
        }
      ]
    ],
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "cover",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "buildNumber": "5",
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.domain.com"
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "package": "com.domain.com",
      "versionCode": 3
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
     
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you do expo eject at any point of your development?

Answer (score 0):

Normally it should work automatically, my suggestion would be to try to `prebuild` your application. So that you can check in the xcode file if the splash screen is there.

Documentation about `prebuilding` is on the following link.

[Link](https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/prebuild/)